# How to pause the audio once after going back to another view controller IOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

Hi I'm playing the audio file in one view controller when i going the another view controller its still playing the audio how to pause the audio when we going back to another view controller.

```
     - (void)dealloc {
    if ([self.audioPlayer isPlaying])
        [self.audioPlayer stop];

        [super dealloc]; 
    }
```

The above code is only works on the navigation view controller if navigate form using the navigation view controller. But i use the normal view controller if i click the back button the audio still plays the audio. This above code is not working on the normal view controller. Please tell how to pause the audio on the normal view controller.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your code in `ViewWillDisappear`

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear{
        if ([self.audioPlayer isPlaying])
            [self.audioPlayer stop];
}
```

Comment: pls tell where i have to call this function i called this function in viewdidload its still not working please tell how to make it

Comment: viewWilldisappear not viewDidLoad

Comment: ok please tell me where ihave to put this code or where i have to call this function

Comment: in your viewController